# Beginner(looping statements and conditional statements in java)

Tags: java

It shows compilation error:
 Compile Message

Solution.java:19: error: unexpected type
                if((N%2=0) && (N>=2 && N<=5))
                     ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int N = s.nextInt();
        if (N % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }

        if ((N % 2 = 0) && (N >= 2 && N <= 5)) {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is to assign a value, `==` is to compare them. You can't assign a value to `N%2`.

Answer (score 4):

`N % 2 = 0` is an incorrect assignment because `N % 2` isn't a variable. Even if it were a correct expression, it wouldn't return a `boolean`, so the line would never compile.

You need `N % 2 == 0`.

Comment: if((N%2==0) &&(N=>6 && N<=20 ))
                {
                   System.out.println("Not Weird");
                }

Comment: Solution.java:23: error: illegal start of expression
                if((N%2==0) &&(N=>6 && N<=20 ))
                                 ^
1 error

Comment: @SourabhChavan `((N % 2 == 0) && (N >= 6 && N <= 20))`

Comment: @SourabhChavan man, it's not serious to ask such a question. Please, learn simple operators

Comment: I would write it as `if (n % 2 == 0 && 6 <= n && n <= 20)`